# Laravel 4.1 working with many-to-many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a Post model with the following function:

```
public function tags() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'refs', 'post', 'tag');

}
```

And a Tag model with a similar function:

```
public function posts() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'refs', 'tag', 'post');

}
```

Now I'm outputting my tags as checkboxes in a foreach loop. What I'm then interested in doing is checking the boxes corresponding to tags that are related to the Post model I'm working with in the given view, but intuition did not solve the issue for me, and I don't know enough technical jargon to formulate a proper search query for an answer on Google.

EDIT:

In case of relevance this is my foreach loop:

```
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <tr>
        <td><label for="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $tag->id }}" name="tags[]" id="{{ $tag->id }}" /></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Which works perfectly. I just need to figure out what my if-statement should be for outputting the following at the end of my input tag in the correct loops.

```
checked="checked"
```

Comment: did you need to add `checked="checked"` for tags which post has only

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Has only what?

Comment: i mean during for loop if post has tag put `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $tag->id }}" name="tags[]" id="{{ $tag->id }}" @if ($post->tags->contains($tag->id)) checked="checked" @endif />
```

So, basically, if the `Post`'s collection of `Tag`s contains the `Tag`'s id, the checkbox will be checked.